# UIImagePickerControllerの横画面固定での表示

Tags: ios, objective-c

UIImagePickerControllerを横画面固定でフォトライブラリを開こうと思っています。
この[記事](http://gokujo.hatenablog.jp/entry/2013/02/05/220642)を参考にしてカメラを起動することはできたのですが、
フォトライブラリのみ開けませんでした。

ご助言をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

いつもこうやってしのいでいます。
ポイントは縦画面をアプリはサポートするが、各 `ViewController` は横画面しか表示しないようにコードで制御するということです。

1. `info.plst` の `Supported interface orientations` に `Portrait (bottom home button)` を追加するなどして横画面固定のアプリでも縦画面を表示できるようにする。
2. アプリ内では横画面固定になるように各 `ViewController` に以下のように横画面のみサポートするようにする

---

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;    // 横画面のみ
}
```

3. `UIImagePickerController` も継承し上記のコードを追加し横画面固定になるようにする。

Comment: 解決することができました。
ありがとうございます！